# How to get the name of the list where the element is dropped

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using this plugin to implement a drag and drop feature in my app :
https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

After an element is moved from a list to another one i successfully trigger a function in which i would like to retrieve : the moved element (this is working) and the name of the list in which the element is dropped, instead i have the name of the list from where the element was picked. I made a really quick function to achieve this but it doesn't work.

```
$scope.drop = function(liste, candidat){
//In this function we try to get the list name in which the element is dropped, for instance : suggeres, retenus_consultant, proposes, etc...
console.log(liste);
```

}

I made a plunker of the current state where i'm stuck at : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zGuviqb2WjfP1G9k8xq?p=preview)

I've been stuck for a while now and maybe someone can explain me how to do this.
Basically i understand why my function returns me the original list of the element, however i have no clue how to get the list in which the element is dropped. I assume the plugin has a way to know that since it change the datas from a list to another one.